# Create malform Xaml document which throws a System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, exception, xamlparseexception

I have a user in Germany which (as the only person out of many) gets a XamlParseException when he runs my application (see stacktrace below).

Unfortunately this exception is notoriously uninformative so I have no idea what's causing it, and I cannot reproduce it.

However, I guess I should be able to catch it and get some additional information.

My problem is - how do I test it? It seems like a simple thing to create a malform Xaml document, but I am simply not able to create one which is not caught at compile time by Visual Studio.

Can someone help me create a Xaml file which file which will throw the exception, so I can try to catch it and deal with it?

```
<exception type="System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException">
<message>Vorgang hat einen ungültigen Status verursacht.</message>
<stacktrace>
bei System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
bei System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(XamlReader templateReader, XamlObjectWriter currentWriter)
bei System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(XamlObjectWriter objectWriter)
bei System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadOptimizedTemplateContent(DependencyObject container, IComponentConnector componentConnector, IStyleConnector styleConnector, List`1 affectedChildren, UncommonField`1 templatedNonFeChildrenField)
bei System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadContent(DependencyObject container, List`1 affectedChildren)
bei System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyTemplateContent(UncommonField`1 dataField, DependencyObject container, FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot, Int32 lastChildIndex, HybridDictionary childIndexFromChildID, FrameworkTemplate frameworkTemplate)
bei System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.ApplyTemplateContent(UncommonField`1 templateDataField, FrameworkElement container)
bei System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ApplyTemplate()
bei System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
```

Comment: take any xaml and remove some of it's important things like quotes, angle brackets, slash etc eg `<TextBlock Text="unclosed />` etc.

Comment: A way that works reliably for me is throwing an exception in the constructor of an object created in Xaml. For example in some `UserControl`.

You can also check (and print the stack trace of) the `InnerException` property inside the `XamlParseException`.

Comment: As @Ale points out, the cause might not be the XAML itself, but code in the constructor of something that you reference in the XAML: custom controls, converters, even view models or whatever you add to resource dictionaries in XAML. I suggest you take a good look at those.